# Identification of physical network interface in linux

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I'm new to linux and I have server with four network cards. I have to identify which physical network interface is assigned to the names eth0, eth1, eth2 and eth3. I have to disconnect cable from eth2 and do not know which network card it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use ethtool.

```
ethtool -p ethX [N]
```

- ethX – network interface name
- [N] – number of second to blink

Example:

```
ethtool -p eth2 15
```

This will blink the network interface eth2 for 15 seconds, then you can see which physical network interface is for eth2

Answer (score -1):

to check the Physical link in linux, use `miitool`.

It shows if your network card is connected or not.

Comment: This will tell you if anything is connected, and the utility can help control the interface, but it is of very little help in differentiating them.  A particular feature of `ethtool` which allows manual control of the LEDs is sometimes helpful.